# How to get information from children

Tags: reactjs

I'm very new to reactjs (three days, in fact). I want to construct a component that lays out its children according to a policy (implemented by the component) and certain children properties. Some properties are passed directly to the children as props upon creation; some other properties, such as its dimensions, are intrinsic to each child. That is, this Layout component will be used like:

```
<Layout>
    <Child1 propx=... propy=...>...</Child1>
    <Child2 propz=...>...</Child2>
    ...
</Layout>
```

and the position of the children will depend on propx, propy, propz, ..., and the children sizes.

Well, the Layout component needs to know the values of its children props and their sizes. At first, I gave the children classes a method 'getProperties' to return the relevant properties and I invoked the method in React.Children.forEach(this.props.children, fn) but I found that the object passed to fn is not the component instance so I cannot call getProperties on it. Then I tried to pass each Layout child an extra property 'uploadProperties' with a callback to be called by the child to tell the Layout what it needs to know. I know I cannot call setProps in the children, so I came up with this:

```
var Layout = React.createClass({
    storeChildProperties: function (properties) {
        this.childData = this.childData || [];
        this.childData.push(properties);
    },
    render: function () {
        var self = this;
        var children = [];
        React.Children.forEach(this.props.children, function (child) {
            var clone = React.addons.cloneWithProps(
                child,
                {key: child.props.key, uploadProperties: self.storeChildProperties});
            children.push(clone);
        });
        this.props.children = children;
        return <div>{this.props.children}</div>;
    }
}
```

It seems to work, but I feel uneasy about two things. First, I don't like attaching 'childData' to the Layout instance (I didn't know where else to put it). Second, I don't know if it's ok to replace this.props.children. Actually, it works even if I don't and I just

```
return <div>{children}</div>;
```

Anyway, is this a reasonable way to get info from children?

Answer (score 3):

You can access children's props via `this.props.children[0].props`.